# Is there a way to download all my Liked / Favorited videos from TikTok?

Tags: download-manager

I have many videos that I marked "like" and "favorite" on tiktok. I want to export them for personal safekeeping.

I did some research and found there are some scrapers / 3rd party APIs out there that can download various things from tiktok, but they don't seem to offer a way to let me put in username and password and retrieve my Likes / Favorites. They're also too hard for non-programmers.

Is there some existing tool for this? I can use both windows and mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chrome extension [myfaveTT](https://myfavett.com/) does what you describe. You login to tiktok.com, which is similar to the phone app, then the extension can see your liked items, and download them.

Besides `Likes`, the extension can also download your `Favorites`, and all videos from all people you `follow`.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myfavett/gmajiifkcmjkehmngbopoobeplhoegad

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

The python [YouTube-DL](https://youtube-dl.org/) utility *despite the name* can actually be used on [100s of sites](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/docs/supportedsites.md) including TikTok and supports the use of usernames & passwords.

It works on Windows & Mac and many others and has a large number of options available.

Ex:

```
youtube-dl --cookies "cookies_files" --referer "https://www.tiktok.com/" "MP4 VIDEO URL" -o "output.mp4"
```

### Note on reading, experimenting & updating

The simple usage of youtube-dl is to supply it with the URL of the video that you would like to download but it is well worth looking into the **documentation** and **experimenting** on what you find as there are options to download &/or convert to specific formats, quality settings, etc. and *specifically to this question* there are options to download playlists, favourites, etc., and convert those to lists of downloads to perform. How & if these work will likely vary from site to site and from time to time so you will need to experiment.

It is also worth noting that ***some*** providers constantly change things *to try to block such tools* so it is a good idea:

1. Before each usage update with `pip install -U youtube-dl` *to get the latest fixes*
2. If something doesn't work give it a day or two and try again.

Comment: How would you download all liked videos? the answer by [ZYinMD](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/81344/76723) does exactly what OP asked for. I agree youtube-dl is an awesome tool, and _can_ be used to download specific tiktok videos.  I would suggest you add to the answer that this is for specific Video URLs

Comment: @Lockszmith Youtube-dl can be used to download a playlist or favourites list and then to download all of the videos in that list - as I personally don't have a tiktok account let alone any liked videos on that service I could not give an example of how to do it.

Comment: Fair enough. per your score, you've been here longer than I and I trust your judgement. I believe the comments here would clarify any question any future reader will have.

Comment: @Lockszmith - I have added some notes which I believe will assist. :-)

Comment: Youtube-dl is great, but has a few issues. I recommend using [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) instead, as it has similar features, but works a bit better, and has more functionality.